# 2nd Ethernet connection "steals Internet focus" from 1st

Tags: linux, networking

I searched the Internet for days, but found no solution

Additionally to the built-in Ethernet port, I have attached a USB Ethernet adapter to my computer (C1) to connect to another computer (C2), that need not and should not have access to the Internet

Problem: As soon as I connect C1 and C2 with an Ethernet cable, I cannot access the Internet on C1 anymore, conversely, as soon as I disconnect C2 from C1, Internet access is restored

C1 only:

```
ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp1s0
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.5
192.168.1.1 dev enp1s0 scope link
```

C1 connected to C2:

```
ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp1s0
10.0.0.0/24 dev enx08beac24aef0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.10 metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.5
192.168.1.1 dev enp1s0 scope link
```

How can I prevent C2 from "stealing the Internet focus" from C1?

---

Debian 12.1 Bookworm, kernel 6.1.0

Comment: That will depend on the operation System. please edit your question to include OS, or add a Tag

Comment: What you describe cannot happen with the routing table you present. If you think it does anyway, use Wireshark (or some other network traffic sniffer) to see where traffic is going.

Comment: Which is the IP address of the default gateway defined in C1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further tinkering around, I noticed, that I had `connman` installed, so I ran `connman-gtk`, which placed itself into the system tray

From there, on a trial-and-error base, I switched off the `Autoconnect` option for the `enx08beac24aef0` connection:

[image]

and everything runs fine since

I am a little unhappy with this solution, because it should work even without a network manager installed, and I would have happily edited a configuration file

---

Update on 2023-08-13:

After countless days of research and trial-and-error, I figured out, how to make it work without a network manager installed:

I added

```
allow-hotplug enx08beac24aef0
iface enx08beac24aef0 inet static
  address 10.0.0.10
```

to
/etc/network/interfaces

deliberately leaving out the `gateway` line